# $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\log_e^i}{i} /(\log_e^N)^2 $ =

Tags: limits, summation, logarithms

The value of $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{{(\log N)}^2}\,\sum_{i=1}^N \,\frac{\log i}{i}$$ is

(A) 0

(B) 1

(C) 1/2

(D) None of this

Really stuck on this problem.Please help or give a hint.

Comment: Please show effort.

Comment: Well I tried with $\frac{\log i}{i} = {\log (i^{1/i})}$. Then approached by L'Hospital's rule but cannot reach a conclusion

Comment: Please help....

Comment: (C) is a straightforward consequence of Cesàro-Stolz - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  Can you please tell me what is Stolz Cesaro theorem and how can we arrive at a solution by using it?Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$, we have $f'(x)=\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}<0$ for $x\geq 3$. Thus $f$ is decreasing on $[3,\infty)$. One can see that that
$$\int_3^N\frac{\log x}{x}dx=\sum_{n=3}^{N-1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\log x}{x}dx\leq \sum_{n=3}^{N-1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\log n}{n}dx=\sum_{n=3}^{N-1}\frac{\log n}{n},$$
and
$$\int_3^N\frac{\log x}{x}dx=\sum_{n=3}^{N-1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\log x}{x}dx\geq \sum_{n=3}^{N-1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\log (n+1)}{n+1}dx=\sum_{n=4}^{N}\frac{\log n}{n}.$$
On the other hand by direct calculation
$$\int_3^N\frac{\log x}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}(\log N)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\log 3)^2.$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\log N)^2}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

By Cesàro-Stolz
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\log k}{k}}{\log^2 N}=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{\log(N+1)}{N+1}}{(\log(N+1)+\log(N))\log\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{1}{(N+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)} $$
equals $\frac{1}{2}$.